# Strongly typed object vs Plain XML as response from rest API service ? Which one is best

Tags: xml, wcf, web-services, rest, architecture

We are about to start a service project which will supply data about our domain objects to different clients. We will have clients ranging from ASP.NET web forms/MVC, Classic ASP,PHP and Android App ( Java as backend code)

We are doing some kind of research to finalise which development strategy to use for. We have exeprience writing WCF Services. Is WCF Rest supported architechure ? I read that Rest Architecture returns data as Plain XML/Json . Not strongly typed objects. While writing the previous WCF service and when i consumed it in the Client apps, i really enjoyed the response being strongly typed objects. I guess it is not possible with REST.

I am looking into ASP.NET Web API ( WCF now become this). But this is still in beta and my team is not ready to use something still in beta.

What is the best appproach i should use  ? WCF Service returning stronlgy typed objects or XML ? What are the advantages & Disadvantages of both ?

Answer (score -1):

What is a strongly typed object? :) It is essentially what is perceived as being of the types it anticipates. You can do that only if you have a way to control the server and the client ends of the pipe (i.e. same VMs on both ends, or same languages or proxy/stubs that can marshal/unmarshal to the respective languages).

So, what does that mean? I recommend using WCF with XML/JSON since that is the lingua franca for communication over the wire. You will get over not having strong types once you realize the benefits of weak types over the wire. If you really want strong types, you can use xsd.exe or something similar to generate the proxy for your services.

All that said, it really behooves you to separate the effort to two things:

- Implement domain services using WCF to wrap your backend. These can be just .NET assemblies exposing a contract to the wire protocol services.
- Implement wire services using something that would be friendly to end consumers. Try to make this a trivial effort so that you can create them quickly and cheaply. Something like vert.x or node.js or WebAPI..

Of course, you might already be doing all this and I might be completely wrong. :)